# How to establish a Server PC to host my website?

Tags: server

So I am interested in server PCs and I want to buy one, and I will choose very powerful. But I don't know how to establish the hard disk to be connected to the internet. I want other people to see it when they write it's domain in the search. I am just searching for advice.

Comment: Your question is really too broad as it stands. What is the specific problem you are having? Connecting the computer to the Internet? Running an HTTP server? Routing traffic from the public Internet to the computer on your network? Choosing a hosting facility to install your server in? Ensuring that you have a static, public IP address? Setting up DNS? Buying a domain name? Something else?

Comment: "I will choose very powerful" — Why? Do you have some reason to believe that you are going to need to handle a great deal of traffic immediately?

Comment: Being the administer of a server is a significantly different skill set to being a developer. It requires a whole bunch of skills relating to keeping it secure and defending it from attacks. The skill level implied by your question strongly suggests you would be better off just getting a cheap hosting plan from a hosting service.

Comment: I tend to strongly agree with Quentin, unless you are rock solid on server administration, you would serve yourself better getting a cheap hosting package (GoDaddy/Hostgator/etc) and leave the heavy lifting to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back over your question and this thread and this is what I recommend. You are looking to create a hosting environment for others from what I am understanding. Regardless the platform you select (linux or windows) having a beefy machine is going to be key to this. I would recommend at a minimum for hardware the following specifications. I recommend building a dedicated server with multiple Quad Core processors, 32 GB RAM, 2 or more TB Disk, with provision for backups. If you call say Dell or one of the other big server providers, they can custom-create a build for you that will accommodate your needs. That configuration would be a start; your final build may be beefier according to your needs and budget.

Comment: I am not looking for SEO. I am looking how to make the server to run.

Comment: I want to be host, or server and to host my website on the internet.

Comment: Ok, much depends on the language you plan to run in the website (HTML, PHP, ASP.NET) Which language are you targeting? What database will you use if the site is data driven? This is a very broad topic so I will need you to narrow the focus a bit please :)

Comment: It's .com. Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: I think you may not be understanding what I am saying. What type of website are you going to run? Is this static HTML or is it data driven pages? What kind of Server operating system are you using? Linux? Windows Server? Before I can tell you how to configure it, I have to know what software the server is running on.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to understand. How to establish anything. I am going to install WordPress, but I don't know what should the operating system be.

Comment: Ok, knowing this, now I can explain.

Comment: First, buy a hosting package with a web host, one that using Linux with Apache web server. They can help you with the technical bits. Make sure to register your new domain with the host you chose. I've used DreamHost for a long time and they really help when I get jammed up. Once you've established the hosting, you can use the Control Panel and go into one click installs. Install WordPress to your domain/website. You should be good to go at that point. For customizing, try doing some google searches and wordpress.org is a great source too!

Comment: I am searching not for an online hosting, but a home server. That was a question, long ago. Now I know what I want.

Comment: Oh a home server, gotcha. Ok, so if your question has been answered, can you mark my response please? Thank you!

Comment: But you didn't answer what I needed.

Comment: @Atanas, I revised my original answer because it dawned on me you need actual server specifications. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Atanas, If you plan to use WordPress, I am going to recommend creating a Linux server. Creating this environment will require you to learn the command line commands to setup and configure the server. Start with Red Hat Enterprise Linux as your host operating system. Once you have your physical server and operating system installed, reply back and we'll go to the next step.

Comment: Although it was a long time ago, your answer actually helped me! Thanks for your help!